# Debugging protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use `node debug` to step through a gulp task.

I have tried the following:

```
node debug $(which gulp) protractor --specs=foo/foo-spec.js
```

But I get the following error:

```
< debugger listening on port 5858
connecting... ok
< c:\nodejs\node0.10.37-npm1.4.16-bower1.3.50-gruntcli0.1.13\gulp:2
< basedir=`dirname "$0"`
<         ^
< SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
<     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
```

Can anyone help me understand why I might be seeing this error?

I am using git bash on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using node 0.10.x and your script contains a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), which is a new ES6 feature. I believe node 0.10.x requires the `--harmony` flag to enable template strings (not sure about node 0.12.x, but io.js has this enabled by default).

Although, your question seems to suggest that you have this problem only with `node debug`, but not without `debug`? If so that would be really strange and I'd except it to fail in both scenarios.